# What are they and how do I remove them?

Tags: furniture, wood-repair, surface-preparation, painting, antique

Have an old armoire that I'm refurbishing and have come across these... how do I remove these?
[image: drawer plugs]

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  A little more context would be helpful.  Perhaps a picture showing its location on the armoire?  Is there anything on the other side of the panel they might attach to?

Comment: I'll preface this by saying I don't know what these are! This is relevant since one can't predict how well seated these things are. Are you removing them to discard them, or do you need to put them back undamaged? If you just need them to be gone, gripping (very firmly) with vice grips would be my first suggestion, although just a stout pair of pliers *might* give you enough purchase (probably not, but worth trying if you have no vice grips). How visible is the location, do you need to try your best to make zero marks on the surrounding wood or would a few score marks/gouges be acceptable?

Comment: Is there an "other side" of the hardware? I'm thinking they're fancy carriage bolts and have a nut or some kind of threaded fastener on the other end somewhere. I'm sure that I've seen these before, but I don't recall the details well enough for an actual answer.

Comment: These might be decorative caps… can you get a blade (carefully! blades break!) under the edge and see if you get any movement?

Comment: Closed due to insufficient additional information